# How to bind styles and className in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a function with `tableData` parameter that returns opacity if its true.

```
_addStyles ({ tableData }) {
const getIndex = id === tableData.id ? 0.7 : false;
    return {
      opacity: getindex;
    }
}
```

I also have `<TableComponent>` with `className` as prop. 
My question is how can I add the styles returned by `_addStyles` function to the `<TableComponent>` without `style` as a prop or `inline style`.

Comment: without style prop, what other way you think there is?

Comment: using classname perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to bind the style like this:

```
<TableComponent style={_addStyles(your_data)} />
```

Also, make sure to return number than boolean value because opacity works with 0 to 1 value.

```
const id === tableData.id ? 0.7 : 0;
```

However, if you wanted to bind the style using class name, you don't need do anything, just add a class name and apply your style with that class:

```
<TableComponent className={_addStyles(your_data)} />
```

Now, your method should return class name like:

```
_addStyles ({ tableData }) {
  return getIndex = id === tableData.id ? 'with-opacity' : '';
}
```

In your css:

```
.with-opacity {
  opacity: .7
}
```